# Recompute Computed Observable without resetting the objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, computed-observable

I have recently started playing with Knockout and I have hit a problem. I have tried Googling this in all sort of ways but I couldn't find any applicable results.

Let's say that I have this model:

```
var model = new function () {
    var that = this;

    this.parameterRegex = ko.observable(/\@@{1}\w+/ig);
    this.query = ko.observable('SELECT @@par1 from @@par2');
    this.parameterNames = ko.computed(function () {
        var allParameters = that.query().match(that.parameterRegex());
        return (allParameters == undefined) ? [] : jQuery.unique(allParameters);
    });
    this.parameters = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayMap(that.parameterNames(), function (item) {
            return {
                Name: ko.observable(item),
                Example: ko.observable()
            }

        });
    });
};
```

In the HTML I am binding with the `Parameters` computed observable, but every time the `Query` observable changes and the `Parameters` observable recomputes, I lose all the state of the items in that computed.

What I mean by this is that if I bind a foreach in HTML with `Parameters` and I have some input boxes in that foreach, such as:

```
<textarea name="query" class="form-control" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" rows="10" style="margin-bottom:20px"></textarea>
<div data-bind="foreach: parameters">
    <p data-bind="text: Name"></p>
    <input type="text"></input>
</div>
```

Any text that the user has typed in the input will be lost once the Computed Observeable is recalculated.

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain your code. Does the parameters array change at all? If it does what changes in it? The face that the text changes is the whole point of a computed function. If you don't want it to change then don't make it a computed.

Comment: The parameters array changes according to the string `query`. This is split into an array of strings containing `@@par1` and `@@par2`. As soon as you change the text in the string `query`, the computed will be recalculated

Comment: So what causes it to change?

Comment: In my original post I have added a new textarea which is bound to the `query`. When this changes, the `parameters` will be recomputed

Comment: What do you want to happen if the text area is changed?

Comment: I want that the computed array `parameters` to keep the values that it already has, delete the ones that are no longer there and add the new ones. Currently it resets the array and repopulates it, therefore I lose the state of the objects I already have

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to keep a separate array with the objects in them and then re-use the objects if they exist in the array instead of re-creating them each time.

```
var parameters = [];
this.parameters = ko.computed(function () {
    var newParams = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < that.parameterNames().length; i++) {
        var name = that.parameterNames()[i];
        var result = $.grep(parameters, function(p){ return p.Name() == name; });
        var param;
        if (result.length === 0) {
            param = {
                Name: ko.observable(name),
                Example: ko.observable()
            };
        }
        else {
            param = result[0];
        }

        newParams.push(param);
    }
    parameters = newParams;
    return newParams;
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zb9kk3h/1/)

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If so please select my answer as the solution.